# Fuerte ROS install fails Ubuntu 12.04 with unmet dependencies

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb //packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
[sudo] password for gary: 
$ wget //packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
--2012-12-12 10:40:05--  //packages.ros.org/ros.key
Resolving packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)... 70.35.54.209
Connecting to packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)|70.35.54.209|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1162 (1.1K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

100%[======================================>] 1,162       --.-K/s   in 0s

2012-12-12 10:40:16 (59.8 MB/s) - written to stdout [1162/1162]

OK
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign //packages.ros.org precise InRelease
Get:1 //packages.ros.org precise Release.gpg [198 B]                      
Get:2 //packages.ros.org precise Release [3,046 B]                        
Get:3 //packages.ros.org precise/main i386 Packages [84.0 kB]             
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                             
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease                     
Ign //extras.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                                 
Ign //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease                      
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease                   
Get:4 //extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg [72 B]                      
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                           
Get:5 //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg [933 B] 
Get:6 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg [933 B]         
Get:7 //extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release [11.9 kB]                       
Get:8 //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release [49.6 kB]            
Get:9 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg [933 B]       
Ign //packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign //packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en                        
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release                               
Get:10 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release [49.6 kB]          
Get:11 //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources [20.9 kB]      
Get:12 //extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources [1,898 B]                 
Get:13 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release [49.6 kB]        
Get:14 //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources [14 B]   
Get:15 //extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages [2,713 B]           
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources                          
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Sources           
Get:16 //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Sources [6,763 B]
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources                      
Get:17 //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Sources [695 B]
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Sources                    
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages           
Get:18 //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages [57.0 kB]
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages              
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages                
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages       
Get:19 //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:20 //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages [18.2 kB]
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en                   
Get:21 //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,394 B]
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en             
Ign //extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US           
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en
Get:22 //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en [27.2 kB]
Ign //extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en                       
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en      
Get:23 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources [54.9 kB]
Hit //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en
Get:24 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources [889 B]
Get:25 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Sources [63.0 kB]
Get:26 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Sources [2,940 B]
Hit //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en
Get:27 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages [141 kB]
Get:28 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages [1,979 B]
Hit //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en 
Get:29 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages [129 kB]
Get:30 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [8,121 B]
Get:31 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en [70.6 kB]
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en
Get:32 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en [72.0 kB]
Get:33 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Sources [14 B]      
Ign //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_US         
Get:34 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Sources [14 B]
Get:35 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Sources [3,080 B]
Ign //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en_US   
Get:36 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Sources [14 B]
Get:37 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages [14 B]
Ign //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en_US   
Get:38 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Ign //security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en_US     
Get:39 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages [2,531 B]
Get:40 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en         
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en   
Get:41 //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en [1,637 B]
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US                
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en_US          
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en_US          
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US            
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en_US        
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US  
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en_US  
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_US    
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en_US      
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign //us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en_US  
Fetched 939 kB in 13s (69.7 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-fuerte-desktop-full : Depends: ros-fuerte-nodelet-core (= 1.6.5-s1347135186~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1348604699~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1347124598~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-filters (= 1.6.0-s1347135144~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1350946896~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo (= 1.6.16-s1347170734~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization (= 1.8.14-s1352876104~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-vision-opencv (= 1.8.8-s1349901192~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (= 1.2.3-s1347169792~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.3-s1347135545~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1347130327~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1348604586~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-image-pipeline (= 1.8.5-s1349904529~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-bfl (= 0.1.0-s1347124594~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-diagnostics-monitors (= 1.4.3-s1352875669~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-common-rosdeps (= 1.2.0-s1347123654~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1352875620~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-image-common (= 1.8.0-s1347135209~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-bond-core (= 1.6.3-s1347130095~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-python-qt-binding (= 0.1.9-s1348595568~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-common (= 1.8.4-s1347130647~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-physics-ode (= 1.8.0-s1347123681~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-driver-common (= 1.4.0-s1347139831~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-executive-smach (= 1.2.0-s1347135552~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-stage (= 1.6.6-s1347135364~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-dynamic-reconfigure (= 1.4.2-s1347130094~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.2-s1349904795~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-xacro (= 1.6.1-s1347130592~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model (= 1.8.1-s1347135356~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-bullet (= 2.79-s1347124531~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-pluginlib (= 1.8.0-s1347130240~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry (= 1.8.2-s1347130162~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials (= 0.6.3-s1352879226~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.2-s1352876054~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline (= 1.4.5-s1350943669~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1347123686~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-common (= 1.8.0-s1347135482~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-diagnostics (= 1.6.4-s1347135107~precise) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-navigation (= 1.8.3-s1350944801~precise) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Help me please...........Gary

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50294/fuerte-ros-install-fails-ubuntu-12.04-with-unmet-dependencies/) by [garym](https://answers.ros.org/users/3471/garym/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like it's trying to pull from quantal sources and thus can't find precise dependencies. Did you leave off the 'http:' from your commands? It should be

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

You should copy and paste from the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu) rather than typing it in.

If that doesn't work, maybe try the answer to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/33585/unable-to-install-ros-on-ubuntu-1204/#33604). Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can be a missed 'http:' as **tbh** mentioned, but it also seems that the main repository is broken at the moment. I've got similar issue on freshly installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. Somehow apt-get tried to pull dependencies for i386.

Use one of the mirrors listed in the [Wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors) instead of main repository. It worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2012-12-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2